# Javascript advanced replace - RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex, web

I want to automatically create hyperlinks on any page based on a rule. For example, I want to find all words ending with 'ate' and turn them into hyperlinks, including the word itself. Like:

- 'Regulate' becomes `'<a href="www.myurl.com/Regulate">Regulate</a>'`
- 'Congregate' becomes `'<a href="www.myurl.com/Congregate">Congregate</a>'`

and so on.

At first I tried splitting all childNodes into words, comparing each word to a RegExp, then using the word to construct the new text and do the replace. That did work...but if I apply it to a page of any length it takes forever.

Is there a way to do this with a straight .Replace() RegExp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var re = /\b(\w+ate)\b/g; 
var str = 'your string';
var subst = '<a href="www.myurl.com/$1">$1</a>'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

<kbd>[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/uS9jT8/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thankyou, this is great. Didn't know about this Regex tester thing, either.

Answer (score 0):

This code did a loop to all `a` , check if `a` body terminates with `ate` ,then update its `href` attribute value .

<kbd>[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/Lzakvh76/2)</kbd>

```
var rgx=/\b(\w+ate)\b/g;
$('a').each(function(i,e){
     if(rgx.test($(e).html().trim())){

         $(e).attr('href','http://www.myurl.com/'+$(e).html().trim())
     }

})
```

<kbd>[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/Lzakvh76/2)</kbd>

Comment: I'm not sure OP already have `a` elements and this will [fail](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzakvh76/3/) if it doesn't